# Не могу найти ошибку вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Не могу понять в чем ошибка

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'si_widget_сontacts' not found in E:\OSPanel\domains\wp-course\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-widget-factory.php:61
Stack trace: #0 E:\OSPanel\domains\wp-course\wordpress\wp-includes\widgets.php(115): WP_Widget_Factory->register('si_widget_\xD1\x81ont...') 
#1 E:\OSPanel\domains\wp-course\wordpress\wp-content\themes\sportisland\functions.php(138): register_widget('si_widget_\xD1\x81ont...') 
#2 E:\OSPanel\domains\wp-course\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(292): si_register('') 
#3 E:\OSPanel\domains\wp-course\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) 
#4 E:\OSPanel\domains\wp-course\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
#5 E:\OSPanel\domains\wp-course\wordpress\wp-includes\widgets.php(1799): do_action('widgets_init') 
#6 E:\OSPanel\domains\wp-course\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(292): wp_widgets_init('') 
#7 E:\OSPanel\domains\wp-course\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, A in E:\OSPanel\domains\wp-course\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 61
```

Comment: у вас же написано в чем ошибка, нет класса si_widget_contacts, вызов происходить на строке 138  в functions.php
вы можете добавить код в вопрос, который нахидится выше и ниже этой строки

Comment: /*для самодельных виджетов / передаем строку-ярлык виджета 
    -он должен быть указан внутри класса виджета(в inc)*/
     register_widget('si_widget_text');
     register_widget('si_widget_сontacts');
    
}

/**/
function _si_assets_path( $path ){
   return get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/' . $path;
}

Comment: register_widget('si_widget_сontacts') в этой строке вы пытаетесь вызвать класс si_widget_сontacts которого нет, либо он не подключен

Comment: Darth KYL
Он есть 
class SI_Widget_Contacts extends WP_Widget{
    /*переопределение родительского метода констракт-он особенный тем что он может быть у любова класса и он запускается тогда когда мы строим новый объект(когда обраещаемся к классу )
    */
    public function __construct(){
        /*вызов родительского метода*/
        parent::__construct( 
            /*ярлык для виджета*/
            'si_widget_сontacts',
И он подключен в фанкшн выше
require_once(__DIR__ . '/inc/widget-contacts.php'); 

По этому и не пойму где ошибка

Comment: Ошибки и код надо показывать текстом, а не картинками. Болд тоже лишний.

Comment: SeVlad добавила текстом

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должно работать, вы не правильно указываете название класса в аргументе функции

```
register_widget( 'SI_Widget_Contacts' )
```

Comment: очень странно , в видео сделано именно так как я делала...Но все получилось , спасибо...

Comment: @ЕвгенияУланова если проблема решана вы можете проголосовать за ответ и принять его, спасибо!